# How to implement add() in Java?

Tags: java, testing, junit, addition, assertion

I am extremely new in Java and computer programming in whole. Today I came across a line shown as:
`assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> add(x, 2));` where x is an integer.

I am confused on the add() method inside of the assertThrows(), does this mean add() will be executed? Also, what exactly does add() do? There are two objects inside the bracket, will both be added?

Thank you very much! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It means that `assertThrows` will execute a lambda expression which contains only one statement: `add(x, 2)`.

Comment: Add can be any method, hard to tell what it does, maybe you can take a look into the method's definition. Basically, it's expected that this particular add(x, 2) will throw certain exception. Otherwise assert will throw other exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter in that method is a lambda function. In the context of `assertThrows` it is a method that is supposed to throw an exception of class `IllegalArgumentException`. [Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-lambda-expressions) are some examples and a bit more info on what a lambda expression is.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that the lambda expression will be executed. However, how is add() method implemented? I thought add(element) would just add a new element to the existing set? How is add(element, element) different from only one element inside add()?

Comment: `add()` is a method defined elsewhere, by the user. A different method with the same name can also be used as a member method on other classes such as `Set` or `List`, but this appears to add 2 integers